# Stylesheet not working in django

Tags: python, css, django

I have tried linking a stylesheet to my template in django and it doesnt do anything:

the template(called base.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}base.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to {{ page }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the settings about the static files:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ('C:/Users/GAL/PycharmProjects/sqvatPreAlpha/static/',)
```

The way my project is built:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ldndl.png

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: have you tried: `os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static').replace('\\','/')` ?

Comment: What output are you getting in your page? Use Inspect Element and post what is showing up in your `href`

Comment: That's not enough information to see what's wrong. What is the output. What is not working. Is it serving of static files you know to exist? Is it `STATIC_URL` being empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `{% load staticfiles %}` at the beginning of base.html
Also, it seems you need to add `.css`to your css file.

Comment: You do *not* need to `{% load staticfiles %}` if you are not using said staticfiles tag.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned if this is a dev or production box. If the latter, make sure you run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

This will collect all your static files that you have in the Django project root, and copy them to the STATIC_URL directory. If you are still running into problems after trying this, you most likely have something incorrectly defined in your settings file.